# jQuery vertical tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am following this tutorial: http://mehdi.biz/blog/2010/02/05/vertical-tabs-for-jquery-lovers/

I modified the script so it changes the content using `click`.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
    $items.click(function() {
       $items.removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');

       var index = $items.index($(this));
       $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
    }).eq(index_obtained_from_the_querystring).click();
});
```

I am trying to hide the `#vtab>div` and to show it only when the user clicks the `li`, and hide it again on `mouseover` or somehow. I just cant make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Try binding also the mouse over event:

```
$items.bind('mouseover',function(){
$(this).show();
})
```